# Global sections of a torsion sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve, $\mathcal{F}$ a torsion sheaf on $X$, $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ finitely generated by $ \{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ (or $n:= \dim \Gamma(X, \mathcal{F}) $). Is $\mathcal{F}$ globally generated? That is, is the map $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\to \mathcal{F}_p$ surjective for every $p\in X$?

This is clearly the case when $p$ is generic, as $\mathcal{F}$ is torsion ($\mathcal{F}_p = 0$). And <strike>there are only finitely many</strike> the support is zero-dimensional, but how do I know what happens in these cases?

Comment: Isn't Sacha's answer from your other question a counter-example ? And no, there may not be only finitely many points $p\in X$ where $\mathcal{F}_p\neq 0$.

Comment: @Roland: Sorry, it should be a smooth projective curve. And yes, you are right, it need not be finitely many $p\in X$ with $\mathcal{F}_p\neq 0$. It can be more. I edited the question. It should be correct as stated now.

Comment: You really mean that $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ is finite or do you just need finitely generated ? Alors, is $\mathcal{F}$ coherent or just quasi-coherent ? If $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent, the support is closed and zero dimensional, thus affine...

Comment: It should be finitely generated. I corrected it.